# How to set a maximum size for my container Deque with C ++?

Tags: c++, c++11, data-structures

I need help defining a maximum size of my STD container of type Deque.

[Deque Documentation C++](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/deque)

In this case, I would have to store a maximum number of clients in a given child in a data structure as in the example below:

```
typedef struct Cart {
     int id;
     string clientName;
     int numberOfProducts;
     double purchaseValue;
} Cart;
```

I defined a constant:

```
#define MAX_CLIENT 10
```

And I'm about to define the queues, which must have a maximum of 10 clients:

```
deque<Cart> BOX_1(MAX_CLIENT);
deque<Cart> BOX_2(MAX_CLIENT);
deque<Cart> BOX_3(MAX_CLIENT);
```

But it seems that the structure is still dynamic, even defining the maximum number.

Thanks for the contribution.

Comment: Don’t tag pure C++ questions with the C tag too.

Comment: So what do you want to happen if someone by mistake adds 11 entries?

Comment: You could use std::array of a MAX_CLIENT size and keep the number of elements inserted

Comment: standard containers dont such feature, but whats wrong with `if (BOX_1.size() == max_size) { /*dont insert element*/} else { /*insert element*/}` ?

Comment: Why do you feel dequeue should have a small maximum size? The documentation has `max_size` but that is for documenting unrealistic memory exhaustion scenarios = (total memory - overhead) / (element size+overhead).

Comment: Better use [Boost.Circular Buffer](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_68_0/doc/html/circular_buffer.html) when you need size-limited sequence, it is way more efficient than `std::deque` for that.

Comment: Just don't add more than `MAX_CLIENT` items? And put some assertions where you need to assume that there aren't any?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> I'm about to define the queues, which must have a maximum of 10 clients:
>
> ```
> deque<Cart> BOX_1(MAX_CLIENT);
> ```

To clarify, that creates a deque that contains 10 carts *initially*.

> How to set a maximum size for my container Deque with C ++?

`std::deque` does not support such feature. It is not possible to set a maximum size for it. There isn't any standard container that supports such feature (except technically `std::array` which has a fixed size).

You can yourself write a custom container that does support such feature. You can use a standard container within the implementation of your custom container if you so prefer. A minimal example, which is by no means complete, nor polished:

```
struct MaxContainer {
    void push_front(Cart c) {
        if (internal_container.size() < max_size)
            internal_container.push_front(std::move(c));
        else
            ; // do something else
    }
private:
    int max_size;
    std::deque<Cart> internal_container;
}
```

You could even create a container adaptor, which can adapt any container (with restrictions) and add a max size to it simply by templetizing the internal container type.

---

That said, you don't necessarily need to have a container which enforces the size limit. Instead, you could simply refrain from adding more elements into the container in the code that uses it.

Comment: I was thinking of doing it that way ... but it's a patch on the schedule. I am grateful and I will develop in this same way.

Comment: NB: you'll get a "narrowing conversion" compilation error on creating the queue with curly-brace initialization, when the queue template type is a number (e.g. `char`): it tries to use the `initializer_list` constructor instead of the `size_type` one. It seems that you have to use the parenthesis (i.e.  (`deque(MAX_CLIENT)` instead of `deque{MAX_CLIENT}`).